# Android NDK: How to solve "E/NdkMediaExtractor: setDataSource(path) must be called from Java thread"

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk, jnienv, mediaextractor

I am trying to use Androids `NDKMediaExtractor` in C++ code like this:

```
const char *storageFile = "/storage/emulated/0/mytestfile.mp3";
AMediaExtractor *extractor = AMediaExtractor_new();
media_status_t amresult = AMediaExtractor_setDataSource(extractor, storageFile);
```

This fails with the error message `E/NdkMediaExtractor: setDataSource(path) must be called from Java thread`.

Searching online did not bring me any hints how I can solve this, what I did find though was the source code, the responsible part looks like this:

```
EXPORT
media_status_t AMediaExtractor_setDataSource(AMediaExtractor *mData, const char *location) {
    ALOGV("setDataSource(%s)", location);
    // TODO: add header support
    JNIEnv *env = AndroidRuntime::getJNIEnv();
    jobject service = NULL;
    if (env == NULL) {
        ALOGE("setDataSource(path) must be called from Java thread");
        env->ExceptionClear();
        return AMEDIA_ERROR_UNSUPPORTED;
    }

    // rest of method omitted for brevity
}
```

I hand in a `JNIEnv` when I call my native methods from Java/Kotlin, but `NDKMediaExtractor`does not seem to know about it. How can I solve this?

Comment: Did you switch to another (native) thread before calling `AMediaExtractor_setDataSource`? AFAIK, `AndroidRuntime::getJNIEnv` will not to attempt to attach the current thread to the VM.

Comment: Not that I know of - but I am still learning my ways around the NDK. I have noticed though that if I create and use the extractor directly inside the method that is called from the JAVA side, this problem doesn't occur. But if I instantiate a class, that instantiates another class that builds the extractor, it fails.

Answer (score 1):

you cant just pass JNIenv* between threads you should get it(every time in a native thread) by calling AttachCurrentThread(before calling any jni methods)in the current native thread so that it can be managed as java Thread.Once you do this it should be working.
i.e

```
 JNIEnv* env;
virtualMachine->AttachCurrentThread(&env,NULL);
```

you should obtain env by calling  AttachCurrentThread and now your native thread is managed as Java thread after attaching.So should resolve ur error.

Comment: Please provide more information for further detail.